# Serverless multiple services errorring with AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in our docs here

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

We have a repo with multiple services ~15.  In the deployment step we get the following error intermittently

`AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in our docs here`

When we run the same service again it works.  Could this be due to the number of services we are deploying?

Comment: Please go through [link](https://maxo.blog/building-aws-serverless-web-application/) and let me know how you go.